# jquery: error in mouseenter() mouseleave() animation

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am trying to create a vertical scroll menu in a sidebar of page with jquery with the following code:
`HTML:`

```
<ul class="side-menu">
<li id="menu1" ><a href="#">Item-1</a>
    <ul class="inner-side-menu" id="menu1_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu2"><a href="#">Item-2</a>
    <ul class="inner-side-menu" id="menu2_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu3"><a href="#">Item-3</a>
    <ul class="inner-side-menu" id="menu3_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu4"><a href="#">Item-4</a>
    <ul class="inner-side-menu" id="menu4_inner">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

`JQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#menu1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#menu1_inner').show('slow');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu1_inner').hide('slow');
});
//Similar for #menu2, #menu3 and #menu4
</script>
```

I got a very weired error, in normal condition the code is working well but if i take the mouse over `#menu1/2/3/4` and leaves immediately than the respective `#menu_inner` animates two or three times seems like it animates with same effect multiple times without mouse enters or leaves.

What is actually happening here? and what is the solution?
p.s.:  I tested this in firefox 10, IE9, Maxthon 3 and Opera 11 with same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the animations are queued and they continue to run unless you forcefully stop them. Use `stop` method to stop the previous animations.

```
$('#menu1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#menu1_inner').stop(true, true).show('slow');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu1_inner').stop(true, true).hide('slow');
});
```

`stop(clearQueue, jumpToEnd)`- Stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Comment: Well this works good. but can i set animation start time with this? I mean with `stop` whole `menu_inner` opens abruptly, it is not a good thing for long lists, can i set time for `mouseenter` such that function waits for 1 or seconds before `show()` calls? Thank you

Comment: @Asif - Adding a timer will not be a good idea but still if you want you can use jQuery `.delay(timeInMilliseconds)` before calling `stop()`.

Comment: Because if you keep doing mouse in mouse out the behavior will not be good. But you can I didnt say don't use.

Comment: Use of `delay` just a need not necessity and can be neglected without any problem..

Answer (score 0):

instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function u cud use `hover` function more elegantly.

```
$('#menu1').hover(function()
{$(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);});
```

here is the [official documentation with example](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: This isn't going to fix the problem described in the question. `hover` is simply shorthand for `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek but I have specific reasons for using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, as i can easily set different animation and effect timings for two different mouse event functions.